# Test.Context.BeginTimer doesn't work in vs 212

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I was able to execute the following code in VS 2010 but in 2012 the following does not work. Am i doing something wrong here.

```
[TestMethod]
public void UTestMethod()
{

    TestContext.BeginTimer("t1");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    TestContext.EndTimer("t1");
}
```

it throws NoSupportedException on method BeginTimer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following Microsoft blog, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/geoffgr/archive/2014/08/05/adding-timers-to-coded-ui-tests-running-in-load-tests.aspx, the ability to use timers in a Unit test was removed from Visual Stuido 2012. The blog states that the timer still works when a unit test is placed inside a load test, but standalone, the unit test will throw the System.NotSupportedException. The blog states that a workaround is to use the following line of code just before the beginTimer() call:

if (TestContext.Properties.Contains("$LoadTestUserContext")) //running as load 
testContextInstance.BeginTimer("MyTimerName");

This approach is working on my installation of VS2012, and allows me to have the timers in my unit test and to run it as a single user without putting it in a load test. Removing the functionality in VS 2012 was NOT the best decision by Microsoft. I have found some cases where a timer in unit tests still does not work in VS 2013, but then sometimes it will work in 2013. In any case, in VS 2012, "unit test timers" are consistently broken but the above line of code provides a workaround.

IMHO, Microsoft should a) (preferred) restore the timer functionality to the way it was in VS 2010 or b) at least update the tooltip in intellisense to state that the timer functionality only works in a load test, and update the IDE to show a squiggly warning unless timers are associated with a $LoadTestUserContext variable as shown here. The change in VS 2012 gives Visual Studio load test scripting a confusing and irritating disadvantage in comparison with industry standard tools such as LoadRunner's Vugen.

Answer (score 0):

The primary use of TestContext.BeginTimer is within loadtests. However I think you are running this within a standard unit test. So in this case yes this is a bug.

The workaround here is to use a .testsettings file while running your tests to allow you to get the functionality that you are familiar with.

Hope that helps